# Derive Autonumber based on value from another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, autonumber, dense-rank

I have a SSIS package which has Stored procedure feed in the backend.I have to derive the autonumber logic for this ChannelName.
 **My current code is:**

```
IF @p_channelname ='ABCD'
BEGIN
        ;WITH CTE_AUTONUMBER_PV_AMER AS
                (SELECT RECORDSEQ
                        , 'ABCD'+CAST(@PrevOrderID+DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS AUTONUMBER_UPDATE
                        , AUTONUMBER
                FROM IC_CTXS_TRANSACTION_SOURCEFEED TGT
                WHERE TGT.[INTERFACE NAME] =@p_interface
                                    AND TGT.[FILENAME]= @p_sourcefilename
                                        AND TGT.CHANNEL = @p_channelname
                                        AND  TGT.GEO='America' 
                ) UPDATE CTE_AUTONUMBER_PV_AMER 
                        SET AUTONUMBER = AUTONUMBER_UPDATE
```

The result is :

```
Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD124      00001600      42
ABCD125      00001597      35
ABCD126      00001600      35
ABCD127      00001597      39
ABCD128      00001600      39
```

Here the '123'(@PrevOrderID) is from a previous file.

I want to derive the following results:

```
Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD123      00001600      42
ABCD124      00001597      35
ABCD124      00001600      35
ABCD125      00001597      39
ABCD125      00001600      39
```

The Product SKU's : 00001597    and  00001600 will be constant values.

How can I change the code to get this result?

TIA :)

Comment: Sample input would make this much easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, we have to see the starting data (especially the RECORDSEQ column) in order to help.

Comment: RecordSeq is just the sequence no from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer :)
 Used row_number instead of Dense_rank:

**Query change**

, 'ABCD'+CAST(@PrevOrderID+ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCTSKU ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS AUTONUMBER_UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

change your `ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )` to `ORDER BY (<column with Quantity in your sample>)`

Comment: How can I change the query to get AUtonumber based on ProductSKU values and not Quantity??

Comment: The ProductSKU values are constant : 00001597 ,00001600 ; If i make it - order by (Productsku) the Autonumber will repeat right??

Comment: I tried with order by productsku; my results                                             Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD124      00001600      42
ABCD123      00001597      35
ABCD124      00001600      35
ABCD123      00001597      39
ABCD124      00001600      39

Comment: you always have 00001597  as ABCD123, and 00001600 as ABCD124 - this is `DENSE_RANK` over your ID's. And when you order by Qty you have result as derieved result in your question. What wrong?